# Why $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)} \cong \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Explain why $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)} \cong \mathbb{C}$.

First consider the morphism

$\phi : \frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)} \to \mathbb{C}, \phi(X) = y$

where $y \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of the polynomial $(X^2+X+1)$.
I have to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, i.e. that it is one-to-one and onto.

I've read that the quotient is of dimension two, why is this the case?

Then since $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}A= \dim_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} = 2$, I only have to show that it is onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\w}{\omega}$Let $\w \in \Bbb C$ be a root of $f(X) = X^2 + X + 1$.
Define the map $\varphi : \Bbb R[X] \to \Bbb C$ as the inclusion on $\Bbb R$ and $X \mapsto \w$.
As usual, this gives us an injective map $\tilde\varphi : \Bbb R[X]/\ker(\varphi) \to \Bbb C$.
Moreover, this is surjective since $\tilde\varphi$ is $\Bbb R$-linear and contains the basis $B = \{1, \omega\}$ in the image.

Note that $f(X) \in \ker(\varphi)$ since $\w$ is a root of $f(X)$. On the other hand, $f(X)$ is irreducible and hence, the ideal $(f(X))$ is maximal. This gives us that $(f(X)) = \ker(\varphi)$.

(An alternate argument to show that $\ker(\phi) = (f(X))$ would be to use the division algorithm and use the fact that $\w$ does not satisfy a lower degree polynomial.)

Thus, we have shown that $\tilde\varphi$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb R[x]/(X^2 + X + 1)$ onto $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Ok, got it!I only have a hard time understanding the argument with the basis and that this shows us that it is subjective.

Comment: @vitalmath: Using "basis" and stuff is just a sophisticated (possibly overkill) way of saying. Essentially, all I'm using is the fact that every complex number can be written as $a + b \omega$ for some real $a, b \in \Bbb R$. Since $\varphi(a + bX) = a + b\omega$, we see that $\varphi$ is surjective. In turn, so is $\tilde\varphi$.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure I have understood everything correctly: since $y^2 + y + 1 = 0$, we get $y^2 = -y-1$, and thus $\tilde\varphi(\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)}) = \{a + by , a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Or since $(1,y)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ (cause $y$ and $1$ linear independent) for all complex in $\mathbb{C}$ we can find a preimage in $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+X+1)}$. Thus $\tilde\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: @vitalmath: Implicitly you are also using that $X^2 + X + 1$ is the lowest degree polynomial satisfies by $y$. For example, your $y$ also satisfies $X^3 - 1$ but $\Bbb R[X]/(X^3 - 1)$ is NOT isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the isomorphism theorem. $[ \mathbb{C} : \mathbb{R} ]$ is 2, and $y$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear independent with 1. so $\{1, y\}$ is basis of $\mathbb{C}$.

And using $ \varphi : \mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $ \varphi(1)=1, \varphi(X)=y$. The kernel of this surjective $\mathbb{R}$-linear map is $(X^2+X+1)$.

Comment: Thanks! How do you show that the kernel is $(X^2 + X +1)$?

Comment: @vitalmath If $p(X)\in\ker\varphi$, that means $p(y)=0$. And following is trivial. And reverse is also trivial.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Thanks!